# PHP - Break out of a frame

Tags: php, javascript, frame, break

Is there a way to break out of a frame using PHP?  I have done it with JavaScript, but I would really prefer to use PHP instead.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frames are a client-side issue.  Javascript is the solution, because it is a client-side scripting language that has awareness of the browsing context.  Frames are meaningless on the server-side.

So, only client-side code can do this.  Not PHP.

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't really sure.  Just wanted to see if there was a way to do it without using JavaScript just incase there's the slim chance a user has JavaScript disabled.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side. It merely generates the HTML for a page. As such there is no way for it to determine whether its output is being shown in a frame.

The best PHP can do for you is outputting the Javascript code to break out of a frame.